# Flutter SVG not rendering properly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i have a design which is been converted to svg for me to display it in my flutter.. here is the design.
[image]

but if i render it to my flutter project with this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) is not displaying well. here is the result.
[image]

here is my code

> CarouselController buttonCarouselController = CarouselController();
>
> int pageIndex = 0;   final List imgList = [
> 'assets/1b.svg',
> 'assets/2b.svg',
> 'assets/3b.svg',
> 'assets/4b.svg',
> 'assets/5b.svg',
> 'assets/6b.svg',
> 'assets/background.svg',   ];

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: CarouselSlider(
        items: imgList.map((i) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  i,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Container(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () async {
                        await addPreference('onboard', true);
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/userOption');
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Skip',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: pageIndex == 3 ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        }).toList(),
        carouselController: buttonCarouselController,
        options: CarouselOptions(
          autoPlay: true,
          onPageChanged: (i, r) {
            setState(() {
              pageIndex = i;
            });

            switch (pageIndex) {
              case 6:
                {
                  addPreference('onboard', true);
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/userOption');
                }
                break;
            }
          },
          viewportFraction: 1.0,
          aspectRatio: 2.0,
          initialPage: 0,
          autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 4),
          enlargeCenterPage: false,
          height: double.infinity,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: okay i wil update it with my code now

Comment: Update: the problem shouldn't be with your flutter code, it should be with the svg file you're using. SVG (Vectors) are supposed to be used for straight-forward UI's like a refresh button or delete button etc. In your case its better to use a PNG or webp image.

Answer (score 1):

If you run **svgcleaner** on this SVG it will work. Or if you manually reorder the **defs** to the top.

Comment: okay i am trying this now

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga is there any warning in your console? are you using shadows? are you using filters or blur effects?

Comment: yes i am getting error from the svg file....this is the error : 
 Failed to find definition for url(#paint12_linear_2523_19691)

Comment: svg clearner is not working

Comment: add your svg file where defs are in above question

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga visit this thread, there are manyy solutions offered there, try all and then report here
https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/289